# How can I get a Discord message object as slash command argument?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, arguments, pycord

I'm trying to write a bot using py-cord 2.3.2 under Python 3.9. When the `/pin` command is used, the bot should pin the user's message.

I have this code:

```
@bot.slash_command(name="pin", description="Make a pinned message.")
     @default_permissions(manage_messages=True)
       async def pin(ctp, arg):
        message = arg
        await message.pin()
        print ('Used used the command ""/pin"')
```

I get an error which says:

```
Ignoring exception in command pin:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
  packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 124, in wrapped
  ret = await coro(arg)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
  packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 980, in _invoke
  await self.callback(ctx, **kwargs)
File "/Users/fk/Downloads/amiebot (no config)/tweescord.py", line 46, in pin
  await message.pin()
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pin'

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
packages/discord/bot.py", line 1114, in invoke_application_command
await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 375, in invoke
await injected(ctx)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-
packages/discord/commands/core.py", line 132, in wrapped
raise ApplicationCommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.errors.ApplicationCommandInvokeError: Application Command raised an exception:
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'pin'
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [ask] and the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Note well that this is **not a discussion forum**; we do not care about your level of expertise because [that does not help understand **the question**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343721). We will write answers in a simple style where it appears appropriate **to the question**. But we really do want a **question**, which is why we have a guide titled "How to Ask" and not "How to Post".

Comment: Looks like `message` is a plain string.  Strings do not have a `.pin` attribute.  Why are you trying to do that?

Comment: I edited the question to show proper writing style and to try to fix the formatting. However, there are still many things wrong with this question. Please [edit] the question to make sure the code is indented exactly as you actually have it, and that the error message appears exactly as it should (read the formatting help and make sure you understand how to do this; then copy and paste the relevant text, starting fresh). Then, try to ask a more **specific** question. For example, did you **read** the error message? Do you **understand** it? Is there something you find confusing about it?

Comment: For example: when your function, `async def pin(ctp, arg):` is called, what do you think the `arg` value will look like? That is, what do you think its *type* will be? Does it make sense to try to use `.pin` with something like that? (I know you tried to explain that a message should be pinned when the user uses the `/pin` command, but - **which message**? The one that has `/pin` in it?)

Answer (score 1):

You **can't** get a message directly as a slash command argument. But you can get a `message-id` as a slash command argument.

The only thing you need to change in the function declaration is changing `arg` to `message_id`. After that, you can verify if the message with the specified ID exists.

```py
try:
   message = await ctp.channel.fetch_message(int(message_id))
except discord.Forbidden:
   print("bot is missing permissions to get message")
except discord.NotFound:
   print("message was not found, it doesn't exist in this channel")
else:
   print("message found")
   await message.pin()
```

---

You can read these two little sections for more detailed documentation:

- `channel.fetch_message`: *[await fetch_message(id, /)](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/models.html#discord.TextChannel.fetch_message)*
- How can you create slash commands? *[Slash Commands](https://guide.pycord.dev/interactions/application-commands/slash-commands)*